# C# Template method override in concrete class from abstract base class

Tags: c#, templates

I have the following code which has a `Base` class containing an abstract template method, which in the derived classes is overridden using concrete types.

```
class MyObj
{
   private string name;
   public string Name { get; set; }
};

class MyObj2
{
  private string value
  public string Value { get; set; }
}

abstract class Base
{
  public abstract string toString<T>(T t);
  public void doSomething<T>(T t)
  {
    string myValue = toString<T)(t);
    ...
  }
};

class MyClass : Base
{
  public override string toString<MyObj>(MyObj o)
  {
     return o.Name;
  }
}

class MyClass2 : Base
{
  public override string toString<MyObj2>(MyObj2 o)
  {
     return o.Value;
  }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like the implementations of `toString()` in `MyClass` or `MyClass2`, giving an error message along the lines of:

> 'MyObj' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'MyObj' accepting a first argument of type 'MyObj' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: As an aside, it's useful if you use conventional names even for sample code - methods in .NET conventionally start with a capital letter.

Comment: @Jon, my bad, I predominantly code in C++ and C# is very new to me, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to provide an implementation for one specific type argument. You can't do that, and it doesn't make sense - it's not clear what would happen if the *caller* passed in a different type argument, e.g.

```
Base b = new MyClass2();
b.doSomething<int>(10);
```

(At the moment, your `MyObj` and `MyObj2` in the methods are being treated as type parameters rather than as the types themselves, which is why the compiler doesn't know anything about your `Name` or `Value` properties.)

It sounds like really it should be the *class* which is generic:

```
abstract class Base<T>
{
  public abstract string ToString(T t);
  public void DoSomething(T t)
  {
    string myValue = ToString(t);
    ...
  }
}

class MyClass : Base<MyObj>
{
  public override string ToString(MyObj o)
  {
     return o.Name;
  }
}

class MyClass2 : Base<MyObj2>
{
  public override string ToString(MyObj2 o)
  {
     return o.Value;
  }
}
```

At this point, the previously-problematic code wouldn't work, because you'd to use `Base<MyObj2>` as the variable type instead of just `Base`, and you could only pass a `MyObj` to `DoSomething`.

(You might also want to consider making the `ToString` method protected instead of public. That's more common for the template method pattern, although certainly not required.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have gone down this path and it all seems to be working now. -cheers

Comment: `You appear to be trying to provide an implementation for one specific type argument. You can't do that, and it doesn't make sense` actually it makes perfect sense, it's called template specialisation. But unfortunately C# doesn't support it.  (Yet?)

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner: No, it really doesn't make sense. The method is abstract - it would make some kind of sense (but not be supported by C#) to have a virtual method and say "Well, if you call the method with type argument X we'll go into this optimized version" - but it doesn't make sense to say "Here's a generic method - but you can *only* pass type argument X", and you can't know what X is based on the base class. What would you expect to happen with the wrong type argument, calling an abstract method with no implementation for that type argument? Throwing an exception would be horrible IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same considerations as OP. I have a base abstract class that a number of subclasses implement. The majority of the work done is implemented within the base class. There is setup in each subclass constructor. Most subclasses override the ProductRequirementsPass method yet the argument needs to be based on the subclasses required class, not a true generic type. If the object being passed in isn't the correct type then immediately return a false value (or consider throwing an exception).

I have about 10 subclasses that implement the base class that need to pass in an object. If there were only one object per class then I'd just make ProductRequirementsPass method have zero arguments. Yet, notice how I have to do work on 2 different objects. The function shouldn't know nor care which of the two is being passed in.

```
class MyBaseClassService 
{
    protected ObjectType SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeed <T>(T entity)
    {
        ObjectType result = new ObjectType();
        if (entity == null)
        {
            result.Message.Add("The entity does not exist");
            return result;
        }

        if (!ProductRequirementsPass(entity))
            return result;
        }
        
        C();
        D();
        E();
        
        // additional work
        
        return result;
    }
    
    protected void C()
    protected void D();
    protected void E();
    
}


class ClassAService: MyBaseClassService
{
    private ObjectA A1;
    private ObjectA A2; 
    
    public ClassAService(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        A1 = CreateObj(arg1);
        A2 = CreateObj(arg2);

        if(SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeed(A1))
            // do something here
            
        if(SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeed(A2))
            // do something here
    }

    protected override bool ProductRequirementsPass<T>(T template)
    {
        if ((template is ObjectA) == false)
            return false;

        ObjectA obj = template as ObjectA;

        // additional code here

        return true;
    }
}

class ClassBService: MyBaseClassService
{
    private ObjectB B1;
    private ObjectB B2; 
    
    public ClassBService(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        B1 = CreateObj(arg1);
        B2 = CreateObj(arg2);
        
        if(SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeed(B1))
            // do something here
            
        if(SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeed(B2))
            // do something here
    }
    
    protected override bool ProductRequirementsPass<T>(T template)
    {
        if ((template is ObjectB) == false)
            return false;

        AnotherObjectType objB = template as AnotherObjectType;

        // additional code here

        return true;
    }
}
```

This setup works with unit tests verifying my results.

Other solutions:

1. Do the check outside of the SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeed. If the check does not pass then do not call SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeedat all.
2. Find a way to override the SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeed class that calls the base.SomeCheckRequirementAllClassesNeed without the generic param.